# How can i convert a swing application into a executable one?

Tags: java, swing, executable

I want to convert my swing application into an executable one.I am using Neatbeans IDE.Is there any plugin available?

Comment: Please have aloof at [Converting Java to .exe](http://stackoverflow.com/q/147181/1057230)

Answer (score 4):

Use IExpress.exe that is part of Windows. Type iexpress in your start bar search.

Add your executable JAR file to the list.

Your install command would be java -jar "yourJar.jar".

Comment: +1, I didn't knew about such a functionality exists in Windows itself :-) Wish I could upvote it some more times, It simply made me believe that I still doesn't know many a functionalities of Windows :-)

Answer (score 3):

Use [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)

It is a Cross-platform Java executable wrapper which will do what you need.